# How can I solve this problem in starting npm?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install, npm-start

I am getting this problem please help I am learning React JS and also I asked for the first time a question on stackoverflow forgive me if breaked any protocol of asking question.

```
'webpack-dev-server' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! reactapp@1.0.0 start: `webpack-dev-server --hot`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the reactapp@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\-\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-24T09_22_22_523Z-debug.log
```

I tried installing npm install `--save-dev babel-plugin-styled-components` to solve problem as I saw on a YT video but nothing happened.
Please help me out in this problem thank you.

Comment: Read the error carefully - the first line is telling you which package you need to install.

Comment: Do you have `webpack-dev-server` installed?

Comment: yes i have webpack-dev-server installed already.

Comment: How did you install the `webpack-dev-server` or how do you know that it is installed?

Comment: ,"devDependencies": {
    "babel-plugin-styled-components": "^1.10.6",
    "webpack": "^2.1.0-beta.25",
    "webpack-cli": "3.3.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.7.2"
  }
}
From this code written in packagge.json file and with this command npm install webpack --save I installed the webpack.